# Taking an object and adding it to the appropritae collection

Tags: c#, regex, class, inheritance

I am doing a few labs and it has me creating multiple classes that are inheriting from a base class. i have created the base class, a student class that inherits from the base class, which creates a student and a teacher class that inherits from the base class, which creates a teacher. Now i am working on creating a school class that does not inherit any class. i have done most of what it is wanting me to do, but i am stuck on creating the appropriate methods to add the objects to its appropriate classes. I need assistance and guidance on how to create these methods so i may proceed. I am just going to post the Student class that i am working in right now and the instructions. I am not looking for someone to do my homework for me, i just cant seem to find anything online that can guide me in the right directions. thank you for your help.

> Methods
>
> 1. Add(base) - Takes a teacher/student object and adds it to the
>      appropriate collection.
> 2. Print(base[]) - Private method that takes an
>      array of your base class object and prints all the elements of the
>      array.
>
> 3 Print(bool students = true) - Public method that prints out the
>   list of students, or list of teachers based upon the parameter value.
>   This is done by calling the Print(base[]) with the student[] or
>   teacher[] based upon the bool.

```
namespace BaseClass
{
    class School
   {
    List<Teacher> staff = new List<Teacher>();
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public Student Students
    {
        get
        {
            students.Count();
            return Students;
        }
    }
    public Teacher Staff
    {
        get
        {
            if(Staff.EnumProp == Status.Employeed)
            {
                staff.Count();
            }
            return Staff;
        }
    }
    public void Add(Teacher t1, Student s1) //not sure if this is correct or 
                                           //what to do in this method??
    {
        staff.Add(t1);
        students.Add(s1);

//i also need help in the following methods. i am not sure what needs to be put
//in the parameter of the method, based on the instructions.
```

Comment: This is for c sharp. i am sorry i did not put that in the body of my questions.

Comment: thats not necessary and you should not do that. what you need is the tag for `c#` and you already added. so no worries.

Comment: why  you used `students.Count();` and `staff.Count()`? do you know what they do? they just give you the length of that list but thats redundant because you dont really need to count them here.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary earlier instructions they want me to count the length of the lists, which is why i have those there. The instructions i have added are just for the methods i need to create now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on requirement 1, you'd have to `Add(Base c)` and determine the collection to add to from there. e.g. `(c is Teacher ? staff : students).Add(c)`. Normally such a class would have overloads (`Add(Teacher)` `and Add(Student)`) separately as well to be able to add directly.

```
public void Add(Base c) 
{
    if(c is Teacher)
        staff.Add((Teacher)c);
    else
        students.Add((Student)c);
}
```

2 depends on the output type. With assignments outputting to the console is often enough, so you can use something like

```
void Print(params Base[] peeps)
{
    foreach(var c in peeps)
       c.Print();
}
```

No matter how Print is implemented, step 3 is actually very easy. You can just call your Print(Base[]) as stated in the requirements. To get that array, you have to determine which collection to use, just as in req. 1. (it does sound like 2 separate collections are wanted, otherwise a single collection could be used where Base exposes the role of the person).

```
public void Print(bool students = true)
{
    if(students)
       Print(this.students.ToArray());
    else
       Print(staff.ToArray());
}
```

PS, as mentioned in the comments the Students and Staff properties seem to expose some behavior that could be changed, but since that outside the scope of the question, won't go there unless you want us to ;)

Comment: it keeps saying teacher is a type, which is not valid in its given context. also it is saying 'c' is of type BaseClass.BaseClass and it cannot be convert to BaseClass.teacher @ME.Name

Comment: In your code example I see you have a **namespace** BaseClass. Do you have another base class which is the base for Teacher and Student. In other words, do Teacher and Student both inherit from the same class? That class is the BaseClass that should be used here.

Comment: Also changed the methods a bit to default if...elses. List<> is not covariant, so the conditional `?: ` wouldn't work as I first posted. (air coded)

Comment: Ah, alrighty, changed the examples so they use `Base` instead of `BaseClass`

Comment: i figured that out and did do it the way you are showing now, but the problem i am having is when i am trying to do staff.Add(c) it is saying it cannot convert from BaseClass.Base to BaseClass.Teacher. the class they are inheriting from is called Base. BaseClass is the Static void main.@Me.Name

Comment: Oooops, I'm very sorry, not on my sharpest today. They have to be cast first. Altered the code (again LOL)

Comment: ah, i would have never known you would have to explicitly cast Teacher or Student. thank you. i will try this and let you know. i did now i could use overload methods, but the instructions call for one method, so i thought i would challenge myself. @Me.Name

Answer (score 1):

> Add(base) - Takes a teacher/student object and adds it to the appropriate collection.

For adding you can have two methods with same name but different signature. they are called method overloads. Compiler can distinguish between them by looking at the parameters they take.

These methods are both defined in base method. but better design would be to put each method in its appropriate class. (i.e Teacher and Student class)

```
public void Add(Teacher teacher)
{
    staff.Add(teacher);
}

public void Add(Student student)
{
    students.Add(student);
}
```

> Print(base[]) - Private method that takes an array of your base class object and prints all the elements of the array.

If i understood correctly you want to print all elements of student or teacher. thats all?

In your base class you can have private method that prints array.

```
private void Print(Base[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

It is better to override ToString method for both Student and Teacher class. for example this method is required in both classes.

```
public override string ToString() // write this method in both student and teacher classes.
{
    return string.Format("Name : {0} , Age : {1}",studentName,studentAge ); // return optional information of student instance.
}
```

> 3 Print(bool students = true) - Public method that prints out the list of students, or list of teachers based upon the parameter value. This is done by calling the Print(base[]) with the student[] or teacher[] based upon the bool.

You just need a simple check.

```
public void Print(bool students = true)
{
    if(students)
       Print(Students.ToArray());
    else
       Print(Staff.ToArray());
}
```

This only works if its inside Base class behind `Print(base[])`. Otherwise Print(base[]) have to be protected.

A better design would be to add each print method in child classes separately.

---

In your get and set method what you are doing is really useless.

`Count()` is a linq method that counts and gives you the length of list. you can use the property of list itself. `Count`(without parenthesis) which directly gives you the length of list.

Also you dont store the result anywhere so thats why i said its useless. You may want to store the total count. then you can do this.

```
public int TotalCount
{
    get { return staff.Count + students.Count; }
}
```